# Dsplaying content in a carousel only at a certain width not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to display content in a carousel only when the `viewport` width is less than `961px`. As the display window gets smaller I see my content display horizontally (desired), then stack vertically (undesired) then disappear all together (also undersired). I don't want it to stack vertically. Just horizontally and then show in a carousel. But as stated before it disappears when it's suppose to be in a carousel and I can only see the navigation arrows. I would also like the content to be centered when in a carousel. I believe there is something wrong with my `media queries`, but I also think there's more to it than that. Can I use `jQuery` to accomplish this? Here's a link to a codepen i created. (FYI: the navigation arrows do not show in the codepen but i can see them in my browser window)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVwGeB

Answer (score 1):

Check this pen. I hope this is what you are looking for.

use col-md for medium screen and col-sm for small screens such as ipad and tabs and col-xs for mobile devices.

```
div#why-cs div:nth-child(1){
  display: none;
  }
```

the above code causing the disappearing of carousal

http://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/RrNzoL

Comment: Yes. After further review I found that the code you were referring to was the cause of my problems. Can you elaborate on your recommendation of how to use of col-md and col-xs?